# How to detect view changes automatically in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a use case where I need to detect current view being shown to the user to report to Google Analytics. I am aware of [Ionic 2's View Lifecycle hooks](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) but that is not what I am after.

What would like to know if there is a way to 'hook' into ionic's navigation system to subscribe to navigation events and get route or view object every time user navigates the app. Since Ionic 2 is not using Angular2's `Router` I can't use following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    private currentRoute:string;
    constructor(_router:Router,
                _location:Location) {
        _router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                // When the route is '/', location.path actually returns ''.
                let newRoute = this._location.path() || '/';
                // If the route has changed, send the new route to analytics.
            if (this.currentRoute != newRoute) {
                ga('send', 'pageview', newRoute);
                this.currentRoute = newRoute;
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to subscribe to navigation changes in Ionic 2 app?

My current setup as of time of wrighting is:

```
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
```

Comment: Subsribe to the root's NavControllers events like 'ionViewDidEnter' etc. See NavControllers lifecycle events for more info: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: As i mentioned in my question i am aware about those lifecycle events and they not suitable for my use case. I would like to subscribe to navigation events in my provider so i can maintain code in one place. By using lifecycle events i am forced to maintain event handlers on each page

Comment: Not if you subscribe to the roots NavController

Comment: Can you please provide an example hot to subscribe to root NavController? My app is setup using tabs starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to `App` Lifecycle events which are described in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/app/App/)

To be more specific, you need to inject `App` from `ionic-angular` and then add code like this where needed:

```
this.app.viewWillEnter.subscribe(viewCtrl => {
   console.log('Entering new view')
   console.log(viewCtrl)
})
```